# MAX of two rows constrained by another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on something where I need to be able to select the MAX of multiple columns from two rows, where they match in ID on another table, grouped by a `FROM_UNIXTIME(date, "%m%")`.

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/219b6/1)

I put together an SQL Fiddle example above.

In the example I have two tables, `Pairs` and `Data`. The pairs are joined by an `id` (non-primary key). So, `TestDeviceA` and `TestDeviceB` both have an `id` of 1; `TestDeviceC` and `TestDeviceD` both have an `id` of 2.

For each distinct date in the `Data` table, I need to pull the max of the `data1` columns between the two devices, the max of the `data2` columns, and the same for `data3`.

Example:

```
date  |  device      |  data1  |  data2  |  data3 
-------------------------------------------------
1234    TestDeviceA       222       234       555
1234    TestDeviceB       292       204       155
```

The desired results would be something along the lines of:

```
1234    TestDeviceA/TestDeviceB    292   234   555
```

Example Query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, "%m"), FROM_UNIXTIME(date, "%d"), p.id as PairID, GROUP_CONCAT(device SEPERATOR '/'), MAX(data1), MAX(data2), MAX(data3) 
FROM Data LEFT JOIN Pairs p on p.devicename=device 
GROUP BY p.id,date
```

I feel like there may be something im missing in the query.

What would be a more efficient and accurate way of approaching it?

Comment: Your method seems just fine. That's probably the best way to do it in MySQL - the aggregate `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` are used correctly

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason, every so often the MAX() doesn't seem to be aggregating correctly. Debugging it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I ran into was, my `data2` and `data3` columns are `binary(16)` (they store bytes from interface statistics).

I had to add:

```
MAX(cast(s.data2 as unsigned integer)) as data2
```